# "Returning" a list in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I've made the following prolog code:

```
mazePath(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,Maze,Path2) :-
nth0(0,Maze,Row,_),
length(Row,Width),
length(Maze,Height),
validPosition(X1,Y1,Width,Height),
validPosition(X2,Y2,Width,Height),
Path = [[]],
findadj(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,Maze,Path,Width,Height,Path2).

findadj(X,Y,X,Y,_,_,_,_,_).

findadj(X,Y,X2,Y2,Maze,Path,Width,Height,Path2) :-
(Xprime is X+1, Yprime is Y,
validPosition(Xprime,Yprime,Width,Height),\+ member([Xprime,Yprime],Path),
movable(Xprime,Yprime,Maze);
Xprime is X-1, Yprime is Y, 
validPosition(Xprime,Yprime,Width,Height),\+ member([Xprime,Yprime],Path),
movable(Xprime,Yprime,Maze);
Xprime is X, Yprime is Y+1, 
validPosition(Xprime,Yprime,Width,Height),\+ member([Xprime,Yprime],Path),
movable(Xprime,Yprime,Maze);
Xprime is X, Yprime is Y-1, 
validPosition(Xprime,Yprime,Width,Height),\+ member([Xprime,Yprime],Path),
movable(Xprime,Yprime,Maze)),
Result = [[X,Y]|Path],
findadj(Xprime,Yprime,X2,Y2,Maze,Result,Width,Height,Path2).
```

This code is designed to solve a 2d array "maze" which it does fine. When I trace through the code with the tracer I can see that it is finding the correct paths.

My issue is that I cannot get the Path to be "returned" to the prolog terminal (I know prolog does not return values but that is essentially my goal here).
I am not exactly sure why I my Path is not being returned. I realize I am not assigning the variable Path2 to anything but I do not know what to set it as I've tried things such as the following

```
Path2 = [[Xprime,Yprime]|NewPath].
Path2 = Result.
```

But none works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I am leaving out any necessary information.

Also,the following is the output I receive for a given command

[debug] 106 ?- mazePath(0,0,4,3,[[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0]],Path).

true ;

true ;

false.

Comment: `findadj(X,Y,X,Y,_,_,_,_,_).` does not unify Result with Path2

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly the problem.